# Different kinds of natural attacks require multiple instances of the Improved Critical feat

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, natural-weapon

I can pick Improved Critical to enhance my natural attacks, no? When I pick the feat, is it tied to a specific natural attack or all of them?

For example, lets say I have a bite attack and two claw attacks, if I pick Improved Critical, would I have to say when picking it that it applies to the bite attack especially or all natural attacks in general and thus to the two claw attacks as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The feat [Improved Critical](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-critical-combat-) is picked for a lone natural attack

For the purposes of of the feat [Improved Critical](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-critical-combat-), each [natural attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks) seems to be a "new type of weapon." As no further text exists beyond the feat (even the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fo) is silent), examples appear to provide the only proof.

Fortunately, there are plenty of examples: *[From Hell's Heart](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601254229)*'s [addu](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/addu) possesses the feats Improved Critical (bite) and Improved Critical (claw), [*Bestiary 4*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601255756)'s kaiju [Agyra](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/kaiju/kaiju-agyra) possesses the feats Improved Critical (claw) and Improved Critical (tail slap), and [*Bestiary 3*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601253788)'s [magicbane bandersnatch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/bandersnatch/bandersnatch-magicbane) possesses the feats Improved Critical (claws) and Improved Critical (quills). This continues all the way to the [*Bestiary 2*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601252684)'s [wendigo](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary2/wendigo.html#wendigo), which, while its feats include one called Improved Critical (bite, claws), has just enough feats to've taken the feat Improved Critical *twice*.

If one assumes the Paizo design team knows how to design its own monsters, the feat Improved Critical appears necessary for each natural weapon to which it is to apply instead of a creature needing the feat but once for all its natural weapons. However, once taken, the feat does seem to apply to all instance of a natural weapon of the same name if a creature has more than one (e.g. Improved Critical (claw) applies to all of a creature's claw attacks).

Answer (score 3):

Improved critical applies to a given weapon, such claw or bite, not to a weapon group, such as natural weapons. From the text of the feat:

> **Benefit**: When using the weapon you selected, your threat range is
> doubled.

Link to SRD: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-critical-combat-

---

I can't find a direct rules quote which states that natural weapons count as weapons when it comes to feats (but why would they not?). However, at least one feat assumes that one can take the weapon focus feat with a natural attack: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/feral-combat-training-combat

> **Prerequisite**:  Improved Unarmed Strike, Weapon Focus with selected natural weapon.

Weapon focus does not explicitly mention natural weapons or natural attacks: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat---final

> *Choose one type of weapon. You can also choose unarmed strike or grapple (or ray, if you are a spellcaster) as your weapon for the purposes of this feat.*
>
> **Prerequisites**: Proficiency with selected weapon, base attack bonus +1.
>
> **Benefit**: You gain a +1 bonus on all attack rolls you make using the selected weapon.
>
> **Special**: You can gain this feat multiple times. Its effects do not stack. Each time you take the feat, it applies to a new type of weapon.

Comment: Seems to be the case, I looked for a good while for a rule on it myself before I gave up and decided not to answer. I think you have the right answer, though, based on what I could find from other sites. One place I didn't check is the Paizo FAQ, there may be a definitive answer there.